# Auth0 login fails with Node.js web app on Heroku (but success on localhost)

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, auth0, cleardb

I deployed my web app on Heroku (Node.js, Express, ClearDB, Auth0). In terms of login using Auth0, it works at localhost but not online.

- Before using auth0, app works on both local and Heroku.
- According to logs of Auth dashboard, every login is success.

So, I assume that my app failed to obtain tokenID from Auth tenant server only when it is online. I use the following code and get "!user" by console.log('!user') when I run app online (at localhost successfully redirect to /users/)

```
// Perform the final stage of authentication and redirect to previously requested URL or '/user'
router.get('/callback', function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('auth0', function (err, user, info) {
    if (err) { console.log("err1"); return next(err); }
    if (!user) { console.log("!user"); return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
      if (err) {console.log("err2"); return next(err);c}
      const returnTo = req.session.returnTo;
      delete req.session.returnTo;
      res.redirect(returnTo || '/user');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Could anyone tell me how to cope with this problem. Thanks in advance.
*This is my first post on stack overflow and I am very beginner, so let me know if you need more information, I am not sure this post is enough.

Heroku logs:

2020-07-03T16:42:56.343864+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/callback?code=lvDWBEwvEBFg9tSX&state=YbB6XzW0tVqscx1uX8mVslj3" host=bmw6.herokuapp.com request_id=dfa50285-d359-49f3-a046-b524d14a1a4c fwd="126.208.165.39" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=302 bytes=249 protocol=https

2020-07-03T16:42:56.337770+00:00 app[web.1]: !user

2020-07-03T16:42:56.550263+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/login" host=bmw6.herokuapp.com request_id=6dd3b3a8-5bb0-4f74-9c67-75e6f1c3a784 fwd="126.208.165.39" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=302 bytes=402 protocol=https

Console logs from Chrome:

Navigated to https://small-darkness-1722.us.auth0.com/login?...

Following parameters are not allowed on the `/authorize` endpoint: [is_submitting,sso] VM5 lock.min.js:9

Navigated to https://small-darkness-1722.us.auth0.com/login?...

Comment: Can you log out the error message?

Comment: Thank you . I added logs from Heroku and Chrome. Accessed login page and tried to login then login page again.

Comment: code is updated (original one is different from what I use, just mistake)